# Mod Rewrite won't redirect subdomains to new URL format

Tags: mod-rewrite, redirect, subdomain

I'm changing all my subdomains to a single domains.
However, in order no to lose all my SEO I need to do some 301 redirections. My problem is that I have about 10.000 subdomains (it's a website about cities and each city is a subdomain) so I need to make a generic rewrite rule in order to make the new URLs (otherwise my htaccess will be too big).

I tried doing it myself but for some reason, it's doing what it wants to (so I guess I'm doing something wrong). Here is my code:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com/b/^(.*)
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/city/$1/b/$2 [R=301,L]

 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com
 RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/?multi_city=$1 [R=301,L]
```

This is what happens with these two rules.

```
city.domain.com --> domain.com/?multi_city=/
city.domain.com/b/place --> domain.com/?multi_city=/b/place
```

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So, after many hours, I finally fixed it doing this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/b
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.%2/city/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.(.*)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^/event
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.%2/city/%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.mydomain\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.com/?multi_city=%1 [R=301,L]
```

This way I can redirect places and events first and if the URL is not in that format then it will go to the different format URL. It's probably not the most efficient solution but it works for me. Hope this helps to someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first RewriteCond it's wrong:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com/b/^(.*)
```

The '^' symbol says that the string start, it's not part of the group, so I think that you will try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com/b/(.*)
```

Maybe, it will be better:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com/b/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)
```

I'm doing it without testing, if it doesn't work I will make tests later and I'll answer you.

Comment: I changed that but didn't really make any difference.
I've tried other things such as the solution written here [link]http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/14048/mod-rewrite-rule-for-wildcard-subdomains[/link] but still not working.
However if I force one rewrite for each city (such as `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^new-york.domain\.com
`RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain.com/?multi_city=new-york
)they do work perfectly.

Comment: I've got new info regarding this. If I try to remove the www from any URL I should do this:`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.(.+)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.%1/$1 [R=301,L] ` and that will do the trick but if I try to do this `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.mysite\.com(.+)
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mysite.com%1/$1 [R=301,L] ` it will simply ignore the condition rule so I guess the problem should be in that area (or not).